# Weak reference and self refreshing cache manager

Tags: java, web-services, caching, javafx, weak-references

Sorry for the long question, I need to present the environment otherwise you may misunderstand my issue.

## Current state

I have a cache manager< K, V >, that for a given object of class K, returns a holder parametrized by the type V, representing the value associated on a web service to the corresponding K.

### Holder

The Holder classes manage the fetch, synchronization, and scheduling of next fetch, because the cache is designed for multiple parallel calls. The data fetched by the web service has an expiry date (provided in the header), after which the holder can fetch it again and schedules itself again for next expiry. I have 3 classes(for list, map and other), but they are all used the same way. The Holder< V > class has 5 methods, 2 for direct access and 3 for IoC access

- void waitData() waits until the data is fetched at least once. Internally is uses a countdownlatch.
- V copy() waits for the data to be fetched at least once, then returns a copy of the cached V. Simple items are returned as they are, while more complex (eg Map for the prices in a given shop referenced by furniture id) are copied in a synchronized loop (to avoid another fetch() to corrupt the data)
- void follow(JavaFX.Listener< V >) registers a new listener of V to be notified on modifications on the holder's data. If the holder already has received data, the listener is notified of this data as if it was new.
- void unfollow (JavaFX.Listener< V >) unregisters apreviously registered listener.
- Observable asObservable() returns an Observable . That allows to be used eg in javafx GUI.

Typically this allows me to do things like streaming of multiple data in parallel with adequate time, eg

```
Stream.of(1l, 2l, 3l).parallel().map(cache::getPrice).mapToInt(p->p.copy().price).min();
```

or to make much more complex Bindings in javafx, eg when the price depends on the number of items you want to purchase

### Self Scheduling

The holder class contains a SelfScheduling< V > object, that is responsible to actually fetch the data, put it in the holder and reschedule itself after data expire.

The SelfScheduling use a ScheduledExecutorService in the cache, to schedule its own fetch() method. It starts by scheduling itself after 0 ms, rescheduling itself after 10s if error, or after expiry if new data was fetched. It can be paused, resumed, is started on creation, and can be stopped.

**This is the behavior I want to modify.** I want  the self executor to remove the Holder from the cache on expiry, if the holder is not used anywhere in the code

### Cache manager

Just for the information, my cache manager consists of a Map< K, Holder< V > >  cachedPrices to hold the cache data, and a method getPrice(K) that syncs over the cache if holder missing, create the holder if required(double check to avoid unnecessary sync), and return the holder.

### Global Code

Here is a example of what my code looks like

```
public class CacheExample {

    public static class Holder<T>{

        SimpleObjectProperty<T> data = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        // real code removed

        T copy() {
            return null;
        }

        Observable asObservable() {
            return null;
        }

        void follow(ChangeListener<? super T> listener) {

        }

    }

    public static class SelfScheduled implements Runnable {

        // should use enum
        private Object state = "start";

        public void schedule(long ms) {
            // check state, sync, etc.
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long next = fetch();
            schedule(next);
        }

        public long fetch() {
            // set the value in the holder

            // return the next expiry
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public Map<Long, Holder<Object>> cachePrices = new HashMap<>();

    public Holder<Object> getPrice(long param) {
        Holder<Object> ret = cachePrices.get(param);
        if (ret == null) {
            // sync, re check, etc.
            synchronized (cachePrices) {
                ret = cachePrices.get(param);
                if (ret == null) {
                    ret = new Holder<>();
                    // should be the fetch() call instead of null
                    makeSchedule(ret.data, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void makeSchedule(SimpleObjectProperty<Object> data, Runnable run) {
        // code removed.
        // creates a selfscheduler with fetch method and the data to store the
        // result.
    }

}
```

## Expected modifications

As I wrote above, I want to modify the way the cache holds the data in memory.
Especially, I see no reason to maintain a huge number of self scheduling entities to fetch data when those data are no more used. If the expiry is 5s (some web sevices ARE), and I cache 1000 data(that's a very low value), then that means I will make 200 fetch() per second for no reason.

What I expect is that, when the Holder is no more used, the self scheduling stops itself and instead of fetching data, it actually removes the holder from the cache. example :

```
Holder< Price > p = cache.getPrice(1);
// here if the fetch() is called it should fetch the data
p.copy().price;
// now the price is no more used, on next fetch() it should remove p from the cache.
// If that happens, and later I re enter that code, the holder and the selfscheduler will be re created.
Holder< Price > p2 = cache.getPrice(22);
mylist.add(p2);
// now there is a strong reference to this price, so the fetch() method will keep scheduling the selfscheduler
// until mylist is no more strongly referenced.
```

### Incorrect

However my knowledge of adequate technologies is limited in that field. To what I understood, I should use a weak reference in the cache manager and the self scheduling to know when the holder is no more strongly referenced (typically, start the fetch() by checking if the reference became null, in which case just stop); However this would lead to the holder being GC'd BEFORE the next expiry, which I don't want : some data have very long expiry and are only used in a simple method, eg cache.getShopLocation() should not be GC'd just after the value returned by copy() is used.

Thus, this code is incorrect :

```
public class CacheExampleIncorrect {

    public static class Holder<T>{

        SimpleObjectProperty<T> data = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        // real code removed

        T copy() {
            return null;
        }

        Observable asObservable() {
            return null;
        }

        void follow(ChangeListener<? super T> listener) {

        }

    }

    public static class SelfScheduled<T> implements Runnable {

        WeakReference<Holder<T>> holder;

        Runnable onDelete;

        public void schedule(long ms) {
            // check state, sync, etc.
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Holder<T> h = holder.get();
            if (h == null) {
                onDelete.run();
                return;
            }
            long next = fetch(h);
            schedule(next);
        }

        public long fetch(Holder<T> h) {
            // set the value in the holder

            // return the next expiry
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public Map<Long, WeakReference<Holder<Object>>> cachePrices = new HashMap<>();

    public Holder<Object> getPrice(long param) {
        WeakReference<Holder<Object>> h = cachePrices.get(param);
        Holder<Object> ret = h == null ? null : h.get();
        if (h == null) {
            synchronized (cachePrices) {
                h = cachePrices.get(param);
                ret = h == null ? null : h.get();
                if (ret == null) {
                    ret = new Holder<>();
                    h = new WeakReference<>(ret);
                    // should be the fetch() call instead of null
                    SelfScheduled<Object> sched = makeSchedule(h, null);
                    cachePrices.put(param, h);
                    // should be synced on cachedprice
                    sched.onDelete = () -> cachePrices.remove(param);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public <T> SelfScheduled<T> makeSchedule(WeakReference<Holder<Object>> h, Runnable run) {
        // creates a selfscheduler with fetch method and the data to store the
        // result.
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: added a few code examples

Comment: Have you considered using a cache library, like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)? In that case, you can use `refreshAfterWrite` to reload only if the entry has been accessed after the given duration, and combine with expiration to allow the entry to be discarded otherwise. You can also enable reference caching, etc. Using one of the many caching libraries may help simplify this for you.

Comment: The issue here, is that the update frequency is not constant, I rely on the fetch() to know when is next expiry ; and there are other methods I did not show here , that can pause and resume the refresh, eg when the server is down. So I need to have access to the full cycle. I did not know caffeine, it looks good .

Comment: There is a recent feature request to allow the refresh time to evaluate the entry for a custom duration (rather than the fixed). That may or may not help. The attached `CacheLoader` can have `reload(key, oldValue)` overloaded, e.g. to disable reloading as desired. A custom expiration policy per-entry can be set. Please open issues if there are improvements you'd like, and maybe we can suggest workarounds, alternative libraries, and possibly add the missing feature(s).

Comment: Are you sure that you need this long winded novel to explain your actual issue? I searched for a question mark in that text, in the hope to find the actual question, but apparently, there is none. Generally, if you want to cache something, you perhaps want to use a `SoftReference`, rather than a `WeakReference`?